# Laravel 6 - Bind array of implementations in constructor

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-6

I'm trying to inject an array of implementations of a certain interface to a subscriber class.

This is the code in my service provider:

```
$this->app->tag([TrackerServiceOne::class, TrackerServiceTwo::class], 'trackers');
$this->app->bind(EventSubscriber::class, function ($app) {
    return new EventSubscriber($this->app->tagged('trackers'));
});
```

And this is the constructor in my `EventSubscriber` class:

```
public function __construct(array $trackers)
{
    $this->trackers = $trackers;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> array $trackers ]] in class Path\To\EventSubscriber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resolving the `EventSubscriber` using `makeWith` from the service container rather than instantiating a `new` instance:

```
$this->app->bind(EventSubscriber::class, function ($app) {
    return $app->makeWith(EventSubscriber::class, [
        'trackers' => $this->app->tagged('trackers')
    ]);
});
```

This should correctly inject the `$trackers` parameter into the EventSubscriber's constructor.

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#resolving):

> If some of your class' dependencies are not resolvable via the container, you may inject them by passing them as an associative array into the makeWith method:
>
> `$api = $this->app->makeWith('HelpSpot\API', ['id' => 1]);`

---

****Update****

After playing around with Laravel 6, I managed to get this working, albeit not quite as described in the documentation:

```
app()->bind('TrackerServiceOne', function () {
  return new TrackerServiceOne();
});

app()->bind('TrackerServiceTwo', function () {
  return new TrackerServiceTwo();
});

app()->tag([
  'TrackerServiceOne', 
  'TrackerServiceTwo'
], 'trackers');

app()->bind(EventSubscriber::class, function () {
  $trackers = [];

  foreach (app()->tagged('trackers') as $tracker) {
    $trackers[] = $tracker;
  }

  return new EventSubscriber($trackers);
});

$subscriber = resolve(EventSubscriber::class);

dd($subscriber->getTrackers());
```

[Laravel Playground Example](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/44c5a998-5f77-45d0-ac7c-86c5dcad5471)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Still getting the same error with that approach tough.

Comment: @GermánMedaglia Have a look at the updated answer, managed to get it working with some adjustments that weren't in the L6 documentation.

Comment: Thanks again, man. Unfortunately I'm using php 7.3 and that syntax is throwing the following error:
`syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS), expecting ']'`

I guess that syntax is available starting from 7.4. I tried other alternatives with no luck.

Comment: @GermánMedaglia Can you try to run my code again, I made another change to remove the spread operator.